# python script converted using py2exe does not accept arguments?

Tags: python

```
def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'usage: ./wordcount.py file pattern'

  txt = sys.argv[1]
  pat = sys.argv[2]
  Efindtest(pat,txt)
```

After converting the .py file using py2exe, the resulting .exe shows this error:

IndexError: list index out of range
(For the sys.argv[1] line)

does py2exe files do not accept arguments?